# MySQL 2003 Error : can't connect to localhost (10061), but PHPMyAdmin works

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver, sqlyog

I'm trying to connect to the MySQL server that came with WAMPServer locally using **SQLYog**, but it gives me this error:

> Error No. 2003
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

However, phpmyadmin works just fine, and `mysql_connect()` works fine with the WAMP's default login details:

> hostname: localhost
>
> username: root
>
> password: *empty*

The server's on, why can't I connect to localhost on SQLYog with root, when phpmyadmin works fine?

Happens with **HeidiSQL** too. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Is this all happening on one and the same server? What address do you use to open phpMyAdmin?

Comment: it's just one machine--an XP laptop, and the phpmyadmin address is http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a Firewall running?

Comment: The Windows default firewall is, I had tried disabling it entirely, but that had no effect.

Comment: That sounds weird. Have you tried `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: Aren't they the same thing? I _have_ tried both, though. phpMyAdmin uses the former only because of an alias with `allow from 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Never use root to connect your program to the server.  Go through the effort to set up a user with appropriate GRANT capabilities.  This applies even to testing.

Comment: Please read this FAQ: http://webyog.com/faq/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

This is a connection error and not an authentication error (ie. not password etc. problem).  First of all check for firewall setings on the server and the client machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue in HeidiSQL, turned out my plink timeout was too low. As soon as I increased the timeout, my problem was solved!

Comment: OMG I've been tearing my hair for over an hour looking credentials and SSH key on my Openshift Instance, and simply increasing the timeout value fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Arda Good to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use plink connect the mysql host if that is never connected firstly
  plink -v -L 10085:host:3306 user@host

And then config HeidiSQL normally